# Winform TextBox can't display text

Tags: c#, winforms, string

Today I found a strange problem with TextBox.Text, if the string length is too large,the textbox will looks like empty, but actually I still can select/copy/paste, just can't see the characters.

I wrote a small winform to test it, i found that if the string length is longer than 5460,the problem will come out.

I am using Win7 64, VS2010. I know it's non-sence to display such large string in a single line textbox, but I want to know the root cause.

And I also noticed that it's not happend in Win2008, even in Win7 when I using a screen recorder the problem disappeared! So weird!

Comment: I repro.  The caret still works but the text is invisible.  It's a Windows bug.

Comment: I am running into this as well - does anyone have a link confirming that this is an actual Windows bug?

Comment: I have the same issue (Win7 x64). Not only the text is invisible, another problem is that Text property returns truncated text!

Comment: The limit on 2020-12-11 on Windows 10 20H2 seems to be 43679 (visible) and 43680 (invisible). It's independent of the width of the characters (tried with i and m).

Comment: @user1068352: that looks more like a misconfiguration of the `MaxLength` property of your textbox.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206600/setlimittext-in-a-cedit-in-vista-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

You could make an if-checker, that takes a string, checks if the string is longer than allowed. You could then run a function on the string, that return a string cut down to the desired length, perhaps with .. at the end to show that it is shortened.
Perhaps something like:

```
public string Truncate(string source, int length)
{
    if (source.Length > length) 
    {
            source = source.Substring(0, length -2); //-2 because of the ".."
            source += "..";
    }
    return source;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error and setting multiline true resolved it.You can try this

```
<TextBox>.Multiline = true;
```